# Docker error can't copy a file after build it

Tags: docker

I'm trying to copy my `./dist` after building my angular app.
here is my Dockerfile

```
# Create image based off of the official Node 10 image
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git

RUN mkdir -p /home/project/frontend

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /home/project/frontend

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm cache verify

## installing packages
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm run build --output-path=./dist

COPY /dist /var/www/front
```

but when I run `docker-compose build dashboard` I get this error

`Service 'dashboard' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderxxx/dist: no such file or directory`

I don't know why is there something wrong?

if you need to check also docker-compose file

```
...
  dashboard:
    container_name: dashboard
    build: ./frontend
    image: dashboard
    container_name: dashboard
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
...
```

Comment: the output path for build is ./dist but you are copying from /dist directory. It should be ./dist or you can set --output-path=/var/www/front/dist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile `COPY` directive copies content from the build context (the host-system directory in the `build:` line) into the image.  If you're just trying to move around content within the image, you can `RUN cp` or `RUN mv` to use the ordinary Linux shell commands instead.

```sh
RUN npm run build --output-path=./dist \
 && cp -a dist /var/www/front
```